# Java Recursion Array and Max sum path

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, path, sum

ok, Ive been working on this assignment for a while and cant get started fully because of the brick wall I keep running into. 
basically what i need to do is take data from a file and recursively fill different 2d int arrays with the data
for example the .txt file might have:

```
2 <-- number of 2d arrays to have
3 <-- L X W of the 2d array
1 2 4 <-|
4 7 9 <-|-- Data to fill 2d array
2 1 6 <-|
2 <-- L X W of the 2d array
3 4   <-|-- Data to fill 2d array
5 9   <-|
```

so what i was thinking is that i'd use the size to add to the index in order to skip over the data blocks that have already been put into an array. so one array would have
    1 2 4
    4 7 9
    2 1 6
in it for me to work with and the other would have 
    3 4 
    5 9
ive tried this so many ways but it has to be recursive and be able to work with any data in this format..any ideas?

Comment: I don't get your description of what you attempted, but what's difficult on creating a 3x3 array, for example, read the values one by one and fill the elements accordingly? I assume reading the file and building the arrays is the easy part of the assignment ... hmm.

Comment: your question seems very unclear to me. Can you explain a bit more ?

Comment: I have a file with this information in it. I need to recursively fill a 2d array with the separate data sets. There can be any number of cases so it needs to work with basically any Text file with this format. Im pretty new to java so this may be easy. But i cant seem to figure out how to read in the specific information from the file into separate 2d arrays and print it so i can double check they contain the right information

Comment: What did you try? Are you able to read individual lines and numbers? Btw, this looks a lot like UVA online judge.

Comment: i can put everything into one array but i dont know how to separate them into an integer array that i could work with the individual data sets. And im not sure what UVA online judge is; this is just part of a lab that ive been stuck on that our prof gave us

Answer (score 0):

```
    String[size][size] myArray = new String[size][size];
    int row = 0 ;
    int column = 0;

    BufferedReader br = null;

    try {

        String line;

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("The File Path HERE!"));

        //for each line in file
        while ((line= br.readLine()) != null) {

            //split on white space
            String[] row = line.split("\\s+");

            //column index
            for(int i =0; i < row.length; i++){
                  String context = row[i];
                  myArray[row][column] = context;
                  row++;
                  column++;
                  if(row == size) row = 0;
                  if(column == size) column = 0;                
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null)br.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thumbs up if this was helpful!

Comment: this is basically what ive been messing with but my problem is idk how to separate the data sets. where you say do the 2D array stuff.. im at a loss for on. I know how to find the file, even read it all into a 2d char array but idk how to put it into a 2d int array with it SEPARATED at the  size indicators..like in my example problem it should make two different arrays

Comment: give me a few minutes and I'll type something up for you

Comment: This is throwing all the information into context.. which is good that the file is copied into the string, i understand that, but how to use the number of 2d ints and the size to make single 2d arrays for each is the question. Im sorry for the lack of clarity

Comment: so I just updated it show how to populate the 2D array. Let me make another update to show how to process those numbers ...

Comment: @Electrology does that answer your question or no? If I can get an upvote for all of this, I'll keep changing as needed and help you get to your answer.

Comment: the [size] in the array declaration is what im looking for, wouldnt you declare the array after you read the file in order to use the size indicator in the file to assign the dimensions of the array. And the String holding the data ( content ) cant be thrown into an int array so thats why i was thinking i could use a char 2d array and use Character.getNumbericValue(charArr);

Comment: This has been helpful though, Ill upvote you because it did help with clarity but filling the array isnt really the issue, its filling it with the right data.. i.e. for each data block a corresponding int[][] arr is made. i just joined to ask this question and it says that i cant upvote you because i dont have 15 reputation..

Comment: @Electrology No thumbs up?

Answer (score 0):

This is what i meant by using the cases to separate into different arrays to work with individually. Its not recursive like i wanted but it will work..it makes one array that is constantly altered to have the different data sets in it. Later I will put a recursive call in the outermost for loop that uses the cases in order to iterate through each individual case between filling the data for the next part of my assignment. Thank you all for your help and input!

```
File file = new File("filename.txt");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

    int caseNum = scanner.nextInt();

    for (int cases = 0; cases < caseNum; cases++) 
    {
        int size = scanner.nextInt();
        int[][] content = new int[size][size];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) 
            { 
                content[i][j] = scanner.nextInt();
                System.out.print(content[i][j]); 
            }        
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
```